# c++ randomization in parallel

Tags: c++, openmp, random-seed

Counting pi using montecarlo method. Is there any way to make randomization same for any amounts of threads? In essence, what I am looking for is to obtain the same answer for every fixed combination of set n and seed, regardless of the number of threads I use.

```
double montecarlo(int n, int seed)
{
int pts = 0;
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        std::mt19937_64 rng(seed);
        std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);

        #pragma omp for reduction(+:pts)
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            double x = dist(rng), y = dist(rng);
            pts += (x * x + y * y <= 1);
        }
    }

    double pi = 4.0 * pts / n;
    return pi;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? How does it work, or not work? Please take some time to read or refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and [ask]. Also please read about  [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the problem is clearly described in the question: the code does not give the same output regardless the number of threads.

Answer (score 5):

1. Divide `b=n/nthreads`: that's how many iterations each thread will execute. (I'm assuming a `schedule(static)`.)
2. Each thread creates its own random number generator, but *all with the same seed*.
3. Let thread `p` call the random number generator `pb` times.
4. And now you start the parallel loop.

This way the threads will compute the same composite random sequence as a single thread will.

Alternatively, let each thread prime its generator by `p` steps, but in each iteration progress by `nthreads` steps.

Either way you get a composite sequence that is identical to the sequential sequence.

Comment: Note that you do not have to  call p*b times, but there is a discard member function for that purpose.

Comment: You also need to be careful when calculating the number of iterations per thread; if `(n % nthreads) != 0` how the "spare" iterations are distributed will vary depending on the loop schedule.

Comment: @JimCownie That had occurred to me. Maybe set a chunk size to `b` but rounded up?

Comment: Also note, that against most people's assumption, OpenMP has no default ("static") schedule. You should not make any assumption about the distribution of work unless you explicit specify a schedule.